# Android Bluetooth LE Chat example

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to read serial data over Bluetooth LE but can't find any code examples for this type of bluetooth and api19. Does any one have an example?

Answer (score 2):

There is no profile defined for serial data communication over Bluetooth Low Energy till now. For this one can use the Bluetooth classic only.

In any case, Android devices can not broadcast for advertising packets. They can only scan the advertising packets. Hence, these devices will be in Central mode only. But can act as either server or client.

For Bluetooth chat related app example one can refer Android SDK as,
sdk/samples/android-19/legacy/BluetoothChat

The above example is based on Bluetooth classic based on RFCOMM channel for serial communication.

Comment: Do you want to say that if we have BLE in Android, say i have Nexus 5, then I can chat with iOS devices via simple sdk/samples/android-19/legacy/BluetoothChat application.??

Comment: No. I am trying to say that serial data transfer over Bluetooth low energy is not supported as of now. So you can't have chat application over Bluetooth Low Energy. Also you can't have communication between an Android device and iOS device due to latter's security measures. If you want to have a simple chat application over Bluetooth (not over BLE) then you can use the above mentioned application available in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Android 5.0 let mobile to be peripheral. So chat will be possible:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Classic got the SPP profile. This is not how Bluetooth Low Energy works.
In BLE you have 1 or more Services each with 1 or more Characteristics which are basically just bytes in a predefined format which by default can be max 23 bytes.

To send data from one device to another one must be the Master and the other must be Slave.
Android API19 does not support the Slave (Peripheral) role, it seems Google still doesn't understand the importance of Bluetooth Low Energy. It's so much more than just Pulse-readers.

You can send from an Android API19 phone to e.g. an iPhone which can be Slave/Peripheral.

You cannot send from an Android API19 phone to another API19 phone. For this you must use Bluetooth Classic SPP profile.